# Google talk in Sony Ericsson XPeria Mini Pro

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-talk, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I've a Sony Ericsson XPeria Mini Pro with Android 2.3.3 and GTalk didn't came installed. I search it in the market and can't find it.

Is there any way to get it installed?

Comment: Are you sure it's not there? It's a pretty core app. It's very rarely called "GTalk" or "Google Talk" these days, try looking for it under `T` just called "Talk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that may be I could share the apk file through bluetooth from another phone and I succeed. Here are the steps:

All the steps are for the phone which already has GTalk installed.

1. Open file manager.
2. Go to System (outside sdcard) -> applications.
3. Search Talk.apk.
4. Send it to the phone where you want to install GTalk by bluetooth (or any other way).

Once Talk.apk is already in your phone, just click it to install the app.

I think (not sure) the second step requires rooting. Also I'm pretty sure that the native file manager doesn't allow you to go up from sdcard. I would need something like [Es File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd) or [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result).

Answer (score 0):

Odd that it wasn't pre-installed. I think your best bet would probably be to search XDA-Dev and install a separate Google Talk apk.

Comment: I've found it.. I didn't make a BIG search but I found an easier way..